# How to achieve the following keyboard layout in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to get the same keyboard as shows in the picture but is not working for me here's what I tried

```
TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        )
```

Keyboard Layout [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eZKh.png)

Comment: You want your image like https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eZKh.png keyboard?

Comment: yes ,is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code hope it helps you:

```
 Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Contact ',
              labelText: 'Contact No',
              border: OutlineInputBorder()),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        ),
      ),
```

Your Keyboard Screen like : [image]

Comment: Well this is good enough, but can I control the buttons curves and space between buttons?

Comment: are you talking about Phone Keyboard ?

Comment: This is System Keyboard

Comment: @noob that image you provided was from iOS, so it's going to look different on Android